# Apple icon not showing up in bookmark

Tags: html, iphone, tags

I used the following:

```
<link href="https://www.domain.com/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
```

This works for adding a shortcut to the homescreen. However, when bookmarking the page, it defaults to the little compass icon. Is there an extra step to do this?

To clarify, the icon shows up everywhere, (i.e titlebar, i.e. favorites, etc), except the iphone bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

Not difficult, you need a favicon.ico file and ftp that up to the site.
Have a look here http://www.favicon.cc/, or look for favicon.ico in google.
They are very easy to make using photoshop or preview.

Comment: P.s no code involved at all, simply upload the file to the root of your website.download this file to test if you like http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CAcQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fstubby4j%2Fsource%2Fbrowse%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fui%2Fimages%2Ffavicon.ico%3Fspec%3Dsvnab03a33515d63419662b461e6dcc73e0f603dd4e%26r%3Dab03a33515d63419662b461e6dcc73e0f603dd4e&ei=b17bVPMZ8tbsBuGUgZAD&bvm=bv.85761416,d.ZGU&psig=AFQjCNEoddYXdCitr0bsw8-8i6ijr9NuZw&ust=1423749086940037

Comment: Sorry wrong link http://thehanoa.org/css_pirobox/white/favicon.ico-download-i19.ico